# Using same user control multiple time from same aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp page with 2 usercontrols using the same ascx page.

**aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnimages1"  runat="server" Text="View Images Gallery 1"  OnClick="btn_click1" /> 

<ascx:WebUserControlImageManager Visible="false" ID="IMAGES1" runat="server" />
<ascx:WebUserControlImageManager Visible="false" ID="IMAGES2" runat="server"   />
```

In the ascx page:

```
if (this.ID.ToUpper()) = "IMAGES1"  // usercontrol id
panel1.Visible  = true;
if (this.ID.ToUpper()) = "IMAGES2"  
panel2.Visible  = true;
```

However, on button click it always shows the panel2. I tried using session variable on button click but the control is rendered showing panel2 before the session gets fired. I guess the usercontrol is rendered before any postbacks and thus first time this.id always returns IMAGES2. 
Is there a way to fix this.?

Comment: what is in your button click event? btn_click1?

Comment: IMAGES1.Visible =true;

Comment: I notice you have Visible="false" twice on Images2.  can you post your full ascx page?  I'm guessing you have what you posted in your page_load or page_init event.  If you put it in page_prerender it will happen after the click